# Why does it write tags_line to the file twice?

Tags: python, file, encoding

Speaks friend,

I'm building a very simplistic decoder, but I'm pretty new to Python, and I have no clue why it writes the values of "tag_line", which is a list, twice to the file "filen_e".
The list "tags_line is supposed to be used to catch words not known by the decoder, and store them in a separate file.

Here is the entire encoder function:

```
# the encoder function ;; filen_e is the file that stores words that aren't in the dictionary
def encoder(lst, filen=dictionary, filen_e=filen_e, verbose=False):  # wordlist / dictionary ######## >>>> NEEDS FIXING !!!!!!
encoded = []
counter = 1
counter2 = 0
tags = []
tags_nrs = []
tags_line = []

score = False
check = False
with open(filen, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    comprehension = f.read().splitlines()
    if verbose == True:
        print(f"Type comprehension: {type(comprehension)}{comprehension}\n")
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(comprehension)):
            if lst[i] == comprehension[j]:
                # match
                encoded.append(counter)
                counter = 1
                score = True
                break
            if counter >= len(comprehension):
                counter = 1
                print(f"- appending: 0")
                encoded.append(0) # in case there is no match
                print(f"- appending: {i},{lst[i]}")
                tags_line.append([i, lst[i]])  # for storing in file "filen_e"
                break
            counter += 1
        counter2 += 1
    f.close()
    if counter2 > 1:
        s = "s."
    else:
        s = "."
    if verbose == True:
        # output for the function
        print(f"+(Encoder)")
        print(f"Processed: ({counter2}) token{s}")
        print(f"String: {lst}")
        print(f"Encoded string: {encoded}\n")
    logmsg = f"encoder({counter2}) :: 'Processed: ({counter2}) token{s}'"
    log(logmsg)
    if check==True:
        logmsg = f"encoder({counter2}) :: 'Can not process: ({tags}) token{s}'"
        log(logmsg)
with open(filen_e, "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    # tags_line = f"tags: {tags_nrs}:{tags},"
    print(f"- unknown tags: {tags_line}")
    f.write(str(tags_line))
    tags_line = []
    f.close()
return encoded
```

What it records comes back in the output for the program as:

```
+(beta_encoder):
- appending: 0
- appending: 2,homia
- appending: 0
- appending: 4,ducken
- appending: 0
- appending: 6,pls
- unknown tags: [[2, 'homia'], [4, 'ducken'], [6, 'pls']]
    +(encode).reverse encoding

[6195, 5879, 0, 6085, 0, 3700, 0]
```

The last string is the encoded string, with 3x the number 0, which signifies it caught a word it didn't know, as it is showing in - unknown tags: [[2, 'homia'], etc.

Then the content of the file "filen_e", where these unknown tags are supposed to be written, has the following:

```
[[2, 'homia'], [4, 'ducken'], [6, 'pls']][[2, 'homia'], [4, 'ducken'], [6, 'pls']]
```

ChatGPT told me I should clear the value of tags_line at the beginning of the function, but this is already the case, as I initialize it as an empty list, at the beginning of the function.

This is really puzzling.

Note: the file is written in "a" <- append mode, but also when I delete the file it writes it twice. I even reinitialize it directly after it is written, so it can't be the second call to the encoder function.

Furthermore, the "encoder" function, is only called once in my other "bootstrap" function.

```
### bootstrap function ### next encode some text ###
encoded_seq = encode(lst=inputs.split(' '), fwd=False, verbose=True)
print("\n", encoded_seq, "\n")

### FUNCTIONS ###
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I feel really stupid, my other function uses the same encoder function, when you have "encoders" set to True.

```
def store(txt, encoders=True, filen=filename, endl=storeUsingNewline):
    ### as such... duh moment
```